# Unable to construct XML using Ansible's blockinfile module

Tags: xml, module, ansible

I'm trying to construct an xml like below in Ansible using "blockinfile" module.

```
<section name="FAILED!!" fontcolor="RED">
    // To display a field
    <field name="FAILED" titlecolor="RED" value="FAILED!!!" detailcolor="RED" href="bad_{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}.txt"> <![CDATA[  ]]> </field>

    // To display a table
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td value="{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}" bgcolor="" fontcolor="" title="" fontattribute="" href="bad_{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}.txt" align="" width=""/>
      </tr>
    </table>

</section>
```

Note: There will be multiple   Entries .... For that i have written a second blockinfile module.

Below is the relevent part from my playbook code that i tried. However, it fails with error.

```
- name: Construct HEADER
  local_action: blockinfile path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_header.xml" block: |
"<section name=\"FAILED!!\" fontcolor=\"RED\">
   <field name=\"FAILED\" titlecolor=\"RED\" value=\"FAILED!!!\" detailcolor=\"YELLOW\" href=\""bad_{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}.txt"\"> <![CDATA[  ]]> </field>
       <table>"
  run_once: True
  when: outputfiles.rc != 0

- name: Construct XML BODY
  local_action: blockinfile path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_body.xml" block: |
        <tr>
            <td value="Hi" bgcolor="" fontcolor="" title="" fontattribute="" href="bad_{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}.txt" align="" width=""/>
        </tr>
  when: outputfiles.rc != 0

- name: Construct XML FOOTER
  local_action: blockinfile path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_body.xml" block: |
    </table>
</section>
```

However, it fails with below error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/comp.yml': line 40, column 33, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: Construct HEADER\n  local_action: blockinfile path: \"{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_header.xml\" block: |\n                                ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n  mapping values are not allowed in this context\n\nThe error appears to be in '/app/comp.yml': line 40, column 33, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n- name: Construct HEADER\n  local_action: blockinfile path: \"{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_header.xml\" block: |\n                                ^ here\nWe could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with\nmissing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they\nstart a value. For instance:\n\n    with_items:\n      - {{ foo }}\n\nShould be written as:\n\n    with_items:\n      - \"{{ foo }}\"\n"}
```

I'm on the matter version of Ansible.

I'm using blockinfile module for the very first time. Can you please suggest how can I get this to work and meet my requirement.

I'm also not sure if "blockinfile" is the right module to be used for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of syntax errors in your YAML document.

In your tasks, you've used syntax that looks like this:

```
local_action: blockinfile path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_body.xml" block: |
```

It looks like you have confused the legacy `key=value` format of specifying parameters and the YAML mechanism of specifying parameters. You have complicated your life by using `local_action`, which in all cases should be replaced by `delegate_to: localhost`.

You also have some indentation problems in your YAML; when introducing a literal block with the `|` operator, lines in that block must be indented.

If we were to fix the structural problems with your playbook, we would get something like this:

```
---
- name: Construct HEADER
  delegate_to: localhost
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_header.xml"
    block: |
      <section name=\"FAILED!!\" fontcolor=\"RED\">
         <field name=\"FAILED\" titlecolor=\"RED\" value=\"FAILED!!!\" detailcolor=\"YELLOW\" href=\""bad_{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}.txt"\"> <![CDATA[  ]]> </field>
             <table>
  when: outputfiles.rc != 0

- name: Construct XML BODY
  delegate_to: localhost
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_body.xml"
    block: |
      <tr>
          <td value="Hi" bgcolor="" fontcolor="" title="" fontattribute="" href="bad_{{ slist[index] }}_{{ dlist[index] }}_{{ foldertype }}.txt" align="" width=""/>
      </tr>
  when: outputfiles.rc != 0

- name: Construct XML FOOTER
  delegate_to: localhost
  blockinfile:
    path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/fdump/report_body.xml"
    block: |
      </table>
      </section>
```

But while this will run correctly, it probably won't do what you want.

- I suspect you mean `report_footer.xml` or something in your final task.
- The `blockinfile` module will by default surround each block with lines of the form:

  ```
  # BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
  ...
  # END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
  ```

  This will result in an invalid XML document.

From your example here, it doesn't look like you need `blockinfile`, which is used to inserting or updating a block of text in an existing document. Here it looks like you're just creating a series of files that you intend to concatenate together at some point.  You would be much better of reducing this to a single task and using the [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html).

Comment: Cool. I will try to use template and see how it goes. But how do we append the tr thingy using template with loop? By the way Thank you so much  for your answer

Comment: If the answer was helpful you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it, or by voting it up by using the up-arrow. You can put loops in your template, see the [jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures) for information about template control structures.